# How to create a TextView in RecyclerView adapter - Android

Tags: android, textview, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that when a `LinearLayout` is clicked it is suppose to create a new `TextView` for that `LinearLayout`. Unfortunately I do not know how to achieve this.

Here is my `onBindViewHolder` where I am implementing the onClick for the `LinearLayout`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mContentHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mContentHolder.addView(createNewTextView("This is a test"));

        }
    });

}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("New text: " + text);
    return textView;
}
```

When the `LinearLayout` is clicked it creates a `TextView` inside of a function and then it returns the `TextView` but I can not create the `TextView` inside the function because of this line of code,

`final TextView textView = new TextView(this);`

How can I create a `TextView` inside of a `RecyclerView` adapter?

Comment: You can use visibility option for textview and on linearlayout click you can change visibility of textview.

Comment: @Shvet I went with this solution for the time being but unfortunately it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Why not just remove the `final` modifier?